# Why does this text float to the left even though it should float to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

So, I know, I'm a beginner and this might be an obvious mistake but I can't find why the two texts "phone" and "envelope" don't align on the right side.

```
<style>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    body {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }

    .flex {
        display:flex;
        background-color:#FCFCFC;
    }

    .topbar {
        background-color:#FCFCFC;
        height:130px;
        width:auto;
        position:fixed;
    }

    #topinfos {
        font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        color:#504C4D;
        float:right;
        margin-bottom:none;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    #logo {
        height:auto;
        margin-top:30px;
        margin-left:30px;
        float:left;
    }

    #topcategories {
        font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        font-size:18px;
        color:#504C4D;
        margin-top:53px;
        margin-bottom:39px;
        margin-left:auto;
        padding:15px;
        float:right;
    }

    #search {
        float:right;
        height: 10px;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="flex" class="topbar">

    <div id="topinfos">phone: +41 (0) 56 448 99 22</div>

    <div id="topinfos">envelope: info@neuhaus.ch</div>


</div>

<div class="flex" class="topbar">

        <div><img src="NeuhausLogo.png" id="logo"></div>


        <div id="topcategories">PRODUKTE</div>

        <div id="topcategories">LÖSUNGEN</div>

        <div id="topcategories">SERVICE & SUPPORT</div>

        <div id="topcategories">ÜBER UNS</div>

        <div id="topcategories">KONTAKT</div>

        <input type="text" placeholder="search" id="topcategories" id="search">

</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, you should only use id's once, if you have multiple elements which need to share css you should use 'class'. In a single element, you can use id once, but if you want to give an element multiple classes they must be included in a single definition. i.e. class='first_class second_class'

Comment: Hey @Josias58. Welcome to Stack overflow. A few issues with your HTML. First I can see is your class attributes. Instead of using two, like `<div class="flex" class="topbar">` you should use one, and separate the values with a space, like this: `<div class="flex topbar">`. Secondly, you should only use an `id` attribute once per page. You can use the `class` if you need to use something more than once. So `<div id="topcategories">` would become `<div class="topcategories">`, and `.topcategories` in your CSS.

Comment: Also, putting `<link href="https...` inside the `<style>` element likely won't work properly. Put that `<link href="https...` line of code *before* the first `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the class attribute, instead of the ID attribute. An HTML element has a single, unique ID.

```
<div class="topcategories">KONTAKT</div>
...
<style>
.topcategories {
    ...
}
...
</style>
```

In CSS, where `#` specifies an ID, `.` specifies a class.

Comment: Ah, I never exactly knew how to use ids and classes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer this question, the reason your top items don't align right is that their parent div is not the width of the parent. So if you set this div to 100% width they will float right.

Ive taken the liberty of updating your code to the class and id standards. Youll need to update where appropriate

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="topinfos">phone: +41 (0) 56 448 99 22</div>

  <div class="topinfos">envelope: info@neuhaus.ch</div>
</div>

<div class="topbar flex">
  <div><img src="NeuhausLogo.png" id="logo" /></div>
  <div class="topcategories">PRODUKTE</div>
  <div class="topcategories">LÖSUNGEN</div>
  <div class="topcategories">SERVICE & SUPPORT</div>
  <div class="topcategories">ÜBER UNS</div>
  <div class="topcategories">KONTAKT</div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="topcategories" id="search" />
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  width: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.topinfos {
  font-family: "Fira Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #504c4d;
  margin-bottom: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#logo {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.topcategories {
  font-family: "Fira Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #504c4d;
  margin-top: 53px;
  margin-bottom: 39px;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  float: right;
}

#search {
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: So, I created a class for the two text elements and set the width to 100%, then the float to right. One of the two now floats right but is positioned in the middle of the website, the other one isn't affected at all. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.topbar` is a flex container, so add `justify-content: flex-end;` to that container and the items in it will be aligned right:

(you can erase the float settings for `#topinfos`, they have no impact on flex items)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  height: 130px;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
}

#topinfos {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #504C4D;
  margin-bottom: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#logo {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
}

#topcategories {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #504C4D;
  margin-top: 53px;
  margin-bottom: 39px;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  float: right;
}

#search {
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" class="topbar">

  <div id="topinfos">phone: +41 (0) 56 448 99 22</div>

  <div id="topinfos">envelope: info@neuhaus.ch</div>


</div>

<div class="flex" class="topbar">

  <div><img src="NeuhausLogo.png" id="logo"></div>


  <div id="topcategories">PRODUKTE</div>

  <div id="topcategories">LÖSUNGEN</div>

  <div id="topcategories">SERVICE & SUPPORT</div>

  <div id="topcategories">ÜBER UNS</div>

  <div id="topcategories">KONTAKT</div>

  <input type="text" placeholder="search" id="topcategories" id="search">

</div>
```

Comment: I tried that out but it doesn't change anything. I don't know why but somehow one of the two text parts at the top now floats to the right but is stuck in the middle of the website and the other one is still on the left.

Comment: then there must be some additional CSS which you didn't post - as you can see, it works in the code you posted